# fmPictureModeZoom not working on userform

Tags: vba, userform

I have a picture frame in my userform and I just want the picture to fit the frame. I am loading the picture using VBA as the picture needs to change depending on what data is loaded. I keep seeing that setting the mode to zoom should make it work but it doesn't seem to do anything. and the photo is either smaller than the image control or larger and clipped. Picture position also seems to be irrelevant, it always aligns to the top left no matter what option I choose. I can't find any information online of other people having this problem.